# Unable to get existing Hive tables from HiveContext using Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I am trying to get databases or table details of Hive from spark using HiveContext. But I am unable to point to existing Hive Database as shown below:
Spark Version: 2.2.0
Hive Version : 2.3.0

Using below script in Spark Shell to connect to existing Hive Server(127.0.0.1 used below is my machine ip address):

```
scala> val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
hc: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@6dde913e

scala> hc.setConf("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://127.0.0.1:9083")

scala> val df = hc.sql("show databases")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [databaseName: string]

scala> df.show
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
+------------+


scala> val dfTables = hc.sql("show tables");
dfTables: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [database: string, tableName: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dfTables.show
+--------+---------+-----------+
|database|tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+---------+-----------+
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

As shown above I am unable to get the existing Hive databases and tables available. HiveContext is pointing to new database(default) and no tables available.
Below are my hive db listed:

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
mydbbackup
Time taken: 7.593 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> use mydbbackup;
OK
Time taken: 0.021 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
customers
customerspart
customerspart1
Time taken: 0.194 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive>
```

Below is my hive-site.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/hduser/apache-hive-2.3.0-bin/metastore_db;create=true</value>
<description>
JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.
To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide database-specific SSL flag in the connection URL.
For example, jdbc:postgresql://myhost/db?ssl=true for postgres database.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
<value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
<description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value/>
<description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
<description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass</name>
<value>org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory</value>
<description>class implementing the jdo persistence</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Below is my spark conf Directory:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 12 20:22 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Nov  9 22:57 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  996 Nov  9 22:57 docker.properties.template
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1105 Nov  9 22:57 fairscheduler.xml.template
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2025 Nov  9 22:57 log4j.properties.template
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7313 Nov  9 22:57 metrics.properties.template
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  865 Nov  9 22:57 slaves.template
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1292 Nov  9 22:57 spark-defaults.conf.template
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3699 Nov  9 22:57 spark-env.sh.template*
```

Do I need to modify any thing to point to existing Hive server rather than creating new. Kindly help me on the same.

Comment: for that you need to set common metastore between hive and spark

Comment: You dont need to explicitly create a hive contect. You can directly use the spark session created by spark2 to run your queries related to hive. Use scala> spark.sql("show databases")
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [databaseName: string]

Comment: @AmitKumar I tried using the same as you suggested but showing only default database. Could you pls help me configure common metastore between hive and spark.

Comment: I dont see the metastore value updated in hive-site.xml. <property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value/>
<description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
</property>

Comment: can you try starting your spark2 shell as :  spark2-shell --conf hive.metastore.uris=thrift://127.0.0.1:9083

Comment: @Chaithu is the issue is resolved.  I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Start your spark shell as is shown below:

```
./spark-shell --driver-java-options 
"-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9083"
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will give you required result:**

import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val hc = new HiveContext(sc)

import hc.implicits._

val df = hc.sql("show databases")

df.show

Answer (score 0):

In hive-site.xml use properties :

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://<<hostname>>:<<port>>/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>username</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>password</value>
</property>
```

Then,  put hive-site.xml in conf folder of spark installation after it try again